# How can you catch 'Uncaught (in promise) Error' from third party library?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await

If I call a synchronous third-party function that throws errors from an asynchronous function it is calling, how do I catch the error?

```
// some asynchronous function thirdPartyFun calls
function thirdPartyAsyncFun() {
  console.log('thirdPartyAsyncFun() called.');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    throw new Error('Error Message!')
  });
}

// a third-party function I want to call
function thirdPartyFun() {
  console.log('thirdPartyFun() called.');
  thirdPartyAsyncFun();
}

// my function
async function myLocalFun() {
  try {
    // I want to catch any errors this is throwing,
    // but calling this produces 'Uncaught (in promise) Error'
    // in the browser when there are errors
    thirdPartyFun();
    
    // This would work, but I can't call thirdPartyAsyncFun directly
    // await thirdPartyAsyncFun();
  } catch (er) {
    // I want this to get called, but it doesn't!
    console.log(er.message)
  }
}

myLocalFun();
```

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2876mnj3/1/) for the above.

Comment: This is a bug. Ask the provider of the library to fix their code and return the promise from the exposed `thirdPartyFun` so that you can handle their errors.

Answer (score -1):

Your third-party function is not synchronous as you think. The catch block isn't called because when you run asynchronous function execution continues and no exception is thrown. You will have to either add:

```
await thirdPartyAsyncFun();
```

Or

```
thirdPartyAsyncFun().then(() => {
/* Do here whatever you want */
}).catch(error => {
console.log(`error: ${error} `);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/quk4zwLg/1/

Comment: Putting await thirdPartyAsyncFun(); doesn't catch the error. Also, I can't do your second approach because it is a third-party function which I can't change.